# ClassCastException while using :group-by option for scatter-plot in Incanter

Tags: plot, clojure, scatter-plot, incanter

I'm using Incanter 1.9 and I can't get `:group-by` option in scatter-plot function to work. The statement I am currently trying is:

```
 (view (scatter-plot :Sepal.Length :Sepal.Width :group-by :Species :data (get-dataset :iris)))
```

It produces this error:

```
 ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number clojure.lang.RT.doubleCast (RT.java:1222)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct usage of `:group-by` in scatter-plot?

Comment: What type of data does `(get-dataset :iris)` return?

Comment: it returns a core.matrix/Incanter dataset

Comment: Is there any way you could get the whole stacktrace? Consider using [`(pst)`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.repl/pst) in the REPL right after the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct usage of `:group-by`. What you test exactly comes from `scatter-plot` documentation. The example works fine with release 1.5.6 (master).

The release 1.9 is still under development. I did some digging and there had been changes on the way datasets are built and there are some impacts in `scatter-plot`.

The best is maybe to work with the release 1.5.6.

Comment: I'm using 1.9 because I require the core.matrix integration with Incanter